# Laravel 5.6 get all rows as arrays of values using Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent query that returns a collection:

```
$items = Item::get(['id', 'name']);
```

When I convert to JSON I get this:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: "some name"},
    {id: 2, name: "some other name"}
]
```

I want a result like this instead:

```
[
    [1, "some name"],
    [2, "some other name"]
]
```

How can I achieve this with Laravel 5.6 and eloquent ORM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the toArray method

```
$items = Item::get(['id', 'name'])->map(function($item) {
    return array_values($item->toArray());
});
```

Your $item variable will have something like this :

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
     all: [
       [
        1,
        "Peter",
       ],
       [
         2,
         "Juan",
       ],
   ];
```

And the json representation :

```
[[1, "Peter"], [2, "Juan"]]
```

Comment: I get the exact same result as before with this. The keys are not removed and objects remain.

Comment: But when I wrap your return statement in php's `array_values` function I get what I want: `return array_values($item->toArray());`. You may edit your answer to reflect this and I'll accept your answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work with just `toArray()` is because the array returned is an associative array and must be flattened.

Comment: Exactly, I forgot to put the array_values function, my bad, but I am glad that you did solve it

Answer (score 2):

I was getting error about inner `toArray()`, so this worked for me:

```
$items = Item::get(['id', 'name'])->map(function($item) {
    return array_values((array)$item);
})->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) method to achieve that

```
$items = \App\Item::pluck('name', 'id');
```

Comment: pluck returns an object with ids as keys and names as values. Not the same thing I want.